# What are Memory eating PHP scripts

Tags: php, mysql, memory

I have read for years about ways to conserve memory when writing php scripts. But what type of scripts should I really concern myself with. What codes/scripts/call eat the most memory?

**Edit**

This is a question, please do not answer it with a question

**Edit**

What about this. Does something like this eat memory? It needs to be done but should it be freed some how?

```
$manufacture = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["manufacture"]);
$manufacture = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $manufacture);



$SQL = "SELECT * FROM STORE_MANUFACTURERS WHERE manufacturers_id = '$manufacture'";
$result = mysql_query( $SQL );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
$manufacturers_name = $row['manufacturers_name'];
}
```

Comment: `create_function()` is a good way to leak memory.  Every call creates a new global function which is never freed.  Calling it in a loop will rapidly leak megs of ram.

Comment: Its not something specific, just bloated code with a lot of variables tends to take a lot of memory.

Comment: @Frank Farmer Hate to ask but could you be more specific

Comment: All memory allocated by the script is freed as soon as it terminates, which is at the end of each request. You shouldn't really have any concerns unless you are building special scripts or have a website with a very high load. If you have to have this question like this, you probably have neither, so don't worry about it.

Comment: @MichaelHowey I believe that Frank is referring to this function within PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

Comment: This specific piece of code *may* consume a lot of memory. For instance if 'manufacturers_name' is a blob with megabytes of data. Otherwise, this code is fine. Pages on many websites consist of thousands of lines of code like this.

Comment: and even if the `manufacturers_name` is a huge blob. there is no `simple` work around there. If one wants to face that issue it will be over engineering I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many things to think when you go for a 100% perfect out look regarding memory leak. What I do is to follow the coding standards and patterns . and if I get into memory leak trouble even after that I should figure that out with [profiling](http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/profiling-Xdebug-KCacheGrind/Jason_Gilmore12302010.php3) Tools like [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) or [Kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html).

Things Like [Exception safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Exception_safety) should be well maintained

You can use tools like [`memory_get_peak_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) , [`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) to spot the culprit. You may check out this [post regarding Memory Manager](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v521/).

Scripting Languages like PHP uses automatic garbage collection e.g. you don't have to dealloc by yourself. the garbage collector does it for you (using reference counting). but if you want to do it by yourself you may use [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php). but some scenarios has been reported when even unset doesn't do it for you. Some Bugs have been reported regarding this too. [`bug#33945`](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33595) [`bug#33487`](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33487)

[`reference counting`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) will run into problem when both `a:A` and `b:B` have a circular reference so you need the one instance to take the `ownership` and destruct the referred object to break the circle to face this issue.

There are some issues with [strtotime() memory leak `bug#47285`](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47285)

The code you have posted in your edit shouldn't have any concern of having memory leak. I'll quote @GolezTrol in comments

> All memory allocated by the script is freed as soon as it terminates,
>   which is at the end of each request. You shouldn't really have any
>   concerns unless you are building special scripts or have a website
>   with a very high load. If you have to have this question like this,
>   you probably have neither, so don't worry about it.

Comment: One of the major improvements in 5.3 was proper garbage collection, even when faced with circular references.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.performance-considerations.php -- btw, I suspect that simplexml uses a lot of circular references, which can make it a bit of a pig in PHP <=5.2. Bug #33487 is really old -- I wonder if that's been improved in more recent versions?

Comment: Ya DOM too I think. SAX is the safest option. or build your own with SAX

Answer (score 0):

Anything where any code is storing a piece of data will consume memory.

Every variable that is set.

You can test your code using the `memory_get_usage()` function, documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)